# How to copy to multiple destinations with Gradle copy task?

Tags: gradle

I am trying to copy one file to multiple destinations through a Gradle task. I found the following in other websites but I get an ERROR while running this task.

```
def filesToCopy = copySpec{
    from 'somefile.jar'
    rename {String fileName -> 'anotherfile.jar'}
}

task copyFile(type:Copy) {
    with filesToCopy  {
      into 'dest1/'
    }
    with filesToCopy  {
      into 'dest2/'
    }
}
```

> ### ERROR
>
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecImpl.call() is applicable for argument types

Is there a way to copy to multiple destinations in one Gradle task?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you really want them in one task, you do something like this:

```
def filesToCopy = copySpec {
  from 'someFile.jar'
  rename { 'anotherfile.jar' }
}

task copyFiles << {
  ['dest1', 'dest2'].each { dest ->
    copy {
      with filesToCopy
      into dest
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a very handy method.  One drawback though is that when I put an extension variable in for the list: `ext.dispersalList = [ 'dest1', 'dest2', ... ]`; the Task uses the definition-time value (empty) and not the "_build-time_" value.  That means I must repeatedly define the same task in sub-project `build.gradle` files.  Is there a means to _**parameterise**_ tasks so builds can be made more **DRY**.

Answer (score 47):

an alternative way

```groovy
task myCustomTask << {

    copy {
        from 'sourcePath/folderA'
        into 'targetPath/folderA'
    }

    copy {
        from 'sourcePath/folderB'
        into 'targetPath/folderB'
    }

    copy {
        from 'sourcePath/fileA.java','sourcePath/fileB.java'
        into 'targetPath/folderC'
    }
}
```

Comment: `<<` was deprecated in Gradle 4.x and removed in Gradle 5.0. Use `doLast {}` instead.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a general snippet without copySpec for Gradle 4.1. As pointed out the trick is to use a base into and use relative into inside the closures (e.g. from closure).

```
task multiIntoCopy(type: Copy){
    into(projectDir) // copy into relative to this

    from("foo"){
        into("copied/foo") // will be projectDir/copied/foo
        // just standard copy stuff
        rename("a.txt", "x.txt")
    }

    from("bar"){
        into("copied/aswell/bar") //  projectDir/copied/copied/aswell/bar
    }

    from("baz") // baz folder content will get copied into projectDir

    //from("/bar"){ // this will mess things up, be very careful with the paths
    //    into("copied/aswell/bar")
    //}
}
```

Comment: This does not respond to the asked question. The goal is to copy TO multiple destinations not FROM multiple destinations

Comment: This one should be the top answer. Its only flaw is that it requires destination path to have the same root, which should not be the problem in most cases.

Comment: This works perfectly, it is capable of copying multiple files to multiple destinations. To copy only one file, use the same file path in all ```from()```

Answer (score 23):

#### With a Common Destination Base Path

If your destination paths share a common path prefix (`dest_base`), then you can use something like this:

```
def filesToCopy = copySpec {
    from 'somefile.jar'
    rename { String fileName -> 'anotherfile.jar' }
}

task copyFile(type: Copy) {
    into 'dest_base'
    into('dest1') {
      with filesToCopy
    }
    into('dest2') {
      with filesToCopy
    }
}
```

Compared to other answers which use the `copy` method, this approach also retains Gradle’s UP-TO-DATE checks.

The above snippet would result in output like this:

```
dest_base/
├── dest1
│   └── anotherfile.jar
└── dest2
    └── anotherfile.jar
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know that multiple destinations with various`CopySpec`s are possible. I don't know whether this is some new Gradle feature, but it is in fact the best solution, since it provides both UP-TO-DATE checks __and__ does not create multiple tasks (which can be annoying for a high amount of subdirectories).

Comment: This is a proper Gradle solution (and the best one) because, as the author says, it will properly use Gradle's incremental build cache and only build (copy) the input source file(s) if they differ from the output destination file(s).

Answer (score 14):

no there isn't a way to do that atm. I would create seperate gradle tasks for each target directory

```
def filesToCopy = copySpec{
    from 'somefile.jar'
    rename {String fileName -> 'anotherfile.jar'}
}

task copyFileDest1(type:Copy) {
    with filesToCopy
    into 'dest1/'
}

task filesToCopyDest2(type:Copy)  {
    with filesToCopy
    into 'dest2/'
}
```

Comment: +1 This way you retain the benefit of UP-TO-DATE checks (which would be lost by directly calling the copy() method as suggested by some other answers)

Comment: @dnault I havn't mentioned that, but definitely a good point.

Comment: this is the gradle way +1, should be the accepted answer

Comment: Where is used `filesToCopyDest2`?

Comment: `filesToCopyDest2` is a task

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this in a particular order to rewrite a particular string on a set of files.

```
task copyAtoB(dependsOn: [existingTask]) {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from("folder/a") {
                include "*.java"
            }
            // Have to use a new path for modified files
            into("folder/b")
            filter {
                String line ->
                    line.replaceAll("changeme", "to this")
            }
        }
    }
}

task overwriteFilesInAfromB(dependsOn: [copyAtoB]) {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from("folder/b") {
                include "*.java"
            }
            into("folder/a")
        }
    }
}

// Finally, delete the files in folder B
task deleteB(type: Delete, dependsOn: overwriteFilesInAfromB) {
    delete("folder/b")
}

nextTask.dependsOn(deleteB)
```