# How create multiple ZIP files dynamically using Gradle?

Tags: gradle

We have Gradle task to create ZIP file in our project. It is like bellow.

```
task createZipFile(type: Zip) {

    destinationDir new File("$projectDir")
    archiveName 'ABC.zip'  

    from('bin/libs') {
        include '**/*.jar'      
    } 
    ...
}

build.dependsOn(createZipFile)
```

We need to create multiple zip file with different names dynamically. We have tried it as bellow.

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].each { def targetName -> 
    tasks.add(name: "zipIt$targetName", type: Zip) {  
        destinationDir = file("${targetName}.zip") 
        from('bin/libs') {
        include '**/*.jar'      
    }
    } 
} 

task zipAll(dependsOn: tasks.matching { Task task -> task.name.startsWith("zipIt")}) 

build.dependsOn(zipAll)
```

When we try this we are getting the following error.

> Could not find method add() for arguments [{name=zipItA, type=class
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip},
>   build_1bct5119tk0khpl3p142j9qck5$_run_closure6_closure18@47b8c9d

How can we fix this issue with Gradle?

Comment: I suggest you look at this solution: [copy-to-multiple-destinations-with-gradle-copy-task](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13494584/108350), and see if you can adapt it for your question.  The _trick_ seems to be to put the parameters _inside_ the task.  I put your [ A, B, C ] list in a variable and used that within the task body. I think you can make that approach work if you still want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `add` method with that signature, but you can use `tasks.create("zipIt$targetName", type: Zip) { ... }`. For API details, check the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html), which further links into Javadoc/Groovydoc.