# How may I modify a Copy Task's properties on execution?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a Gradle copy task set-up to publish undecorated JAR file(s) for testing and debugging, viz.

Task definition:

```gradle
 task copyJarToStaging( type: Copy ) {
     from jar // shortcut for createJar.outputs.files
     into ( "${rootProject.rootDir}/dist/" )
     rename( '-.*\\.jar', ".jar" )
 }
```

Which works, to put a JAR file into the one directory.  What's really needed is to drop the JAR into one or more different folders under "`dist/`".

Following many trials (and *errors*) I found this version worked for me.

Invoke the copy task:

```gradle
// build.gradle  (module)

assemble.dependsOn copyJarToStaging {
    println "into ==> ${destinationDir}/support"
    into "${destinationDir}/support/"
}
```

However, it doesn't really *smell* right.

Is there a cleaner alternative way?   I would have liked a closure for instance to just append to the `into` attribute -- But it didn't go.

If I wanted the same file in different places, it would be better if I can do something like  take the `into` string and `yield` each value back.

Is part or all of that possible?  Or, am I dreaming???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467498/how-to-copy-to-multiple-destinations-with-gradle-copy-task

Comment: @tim_yates ... Thanks, yes I saw that this afternoon.  That is really a very small side issue.  The main objective is manipulating / editing the **`into`** attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'd create multiple copy tasks

```
['dev', 'staging', 'uat', 'prod'].each { String dir ->
    Task task = tasks.create("copyJarTo${dir.capitalize()}", type: Copy) {
        from jar
        into "dist/$dir"
    }
    assemble.dependsOn task
}
```