# Weird behaviour of a simple gradle copy task

Tags: gradle

I am completely baffled by the gradle behaviour of a `Copy` task into multiple directories.

I intend to copy all files from `src/common` into

- `target/dir1/ps_modules`
- `target/dir2/ps_modules`
- `target/dir3/ps_modules`

Below is how my `build.gradle` looks:

```
project.ext.dirs = ["dir1", "dir2", "dir3"]

// ensures that ps_modules directory is created before copying
def ensurePsModulesDir() {
  dirs.each {
    def psModules = file("target/$it/ps_modules")
    if (!(psModules.exists())) {
      println("Creating ps_modules directory $psModules as it doesn't exist yet")
      mkdir psModules
    }
  }
}

task copyCommons(type: Copy) {
  doFirst {
    ensurePsModulesDir()
  }

  from("src/common")
  dirs.each {
    into "target/$it/ps_modules"
  }
}
```

The result of running the command `./gradlew copyCommons` is completely weird.

The folder creation works as expected, however, the contents/files are copied only in the `target/dir3/ps_modules` directory. The rest two directories remain empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the screen grab of target directory tree once the job is run:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like:

```
task copyCommons(type: Copy) {
    dirs.each {
        with copySpec {
            from "src/common"
            into "target/$it/ps_modules"
        }
    }
}
```

I think you can get rid of the `ensurePsModulesDir()` with this change

*** edit ***

it seems that the copy task is forcing us to set a destination dir. You might think that setting `destinationDir = '.'` is ok but it's used in up-to-date checking so likely the task will NEVER be considered up-to-date so will always run. I suggest you use `project.copy(...)` instead of a `Copy` task. Eg

```
task copyCommons {
   // setup inputs and outputs manually 
   inputs.dir "src/common"
   dirs.each {
       outputs.dir "target/$it/ps_modules"
   }

   doLast {
       dirs.each { dir ->
           project.copy {
               from  "src/common"
               into "target/$dir/ps_modules"
           } 
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have suggested an edit without which it was failing with error: "No value has been specified for property 'destinationDir'."

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a single `into` for a task of type `Copy`. In this particular example gradle behaves as expected. Since `dir3` is the last element on the list it is finally configured as a destination. Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467498/how-to-copy-to-multiple-destinations-with-gradle-copy-task) question - which you can find helpful. Also [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/copy-task-doesnt-update-multiple-destinations-properly/1343) thread might be helpful as well.