# Gradle- Copy Dependencies of Sub Projects into respective folder of Sub Projects

Tags: gradle

From root, I am basically trying to fetch the dependencies of each sub project and copy into a directory named dependency within each subproject

I have a root Project and in that build.gradle file i have a task like below:

```
task copyDependencies(type:Copy) {

    nonTestProjects.each {
        delete rootProject.project(it).file('dependencies')
        from rootProject.project(it).configurations.runtime
        intorootProject.project(it).file('dependencies/')
    }
}
```

Inside the Sub Projects build.gradle, i have dependencies as below:

```
 dependencies
 {
    implementation "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:$protobufVersion"
    implementation "io.netty:netty:$nettyVersion"
    implementation "xmlpull:xmlpull:$xmlPullVersion"
}
```

On running the task copydependencies from root, i am getting error as below:

> Could not get unknown property 'runtime' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfig
>   urationContainer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error `Could not get unknown property 'runtime' for configuration container` because when gradle configures your root project and tries to create the task `copyDependencies`, the subprojects have not yet been evaluated, so Gradle doesn't know about "runtime" configuration at this stage ( `java` plugin has not yet been applied to subprojects).

So one solution would be to wrap this task creation into a `gradle.projectsEvaluated` lifecycle hook:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    task copyDependencies(type:Copy) {
        // task definition ...
    }
}
```

But then you will have other issues because you want to copy different sources to different destination directories (see [How to copy to multiple destinations with Gradle copy task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467498/how-to-copy-to-multiple-destinations-with-gradle-copy-task) for possible solution to this issue)

I think a better way would be to create different `copyDependencies` tasks, one per subproject , and create an "aggregator" task in root project which will depend on these subprojects's tasks:

```
// aggregator task at root project level
task copyDependencies

// create copydependencies task for each (non-test) subproject
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    nonTestProjects.each {
        Project proj = project(it)
        Task task = proj.task('copyDependencies', type: Copy) {
            from proj.configurations.runtimeClasspath
            into proj.file("dependencies")
            doFirst {
                file('dependencies').deleteDir()
            }
        }
        copyDependencies.dependsOn task
    }
}
```