# Zip directory to multiple destinations using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build, zip

Is it possible with Gradle's [Zip](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html) task to copy the resulting zip into multiple destinations?

AFAIK you can only zip multiple input directories with only one output destination. Is there a way to zip a directory and copy the archive to multiple destinations (in one single task)? Since I'm bound to using Gradle v5.0, a solution for that version of Gradle would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal action of `Zip` tasks will only output the zip file to a single directory. If you don't want create additional `Copy` tasks, you may use a `doLast` closure and use the method `copy` provided by the `Project` instance.

```
task myZip(type: Zip) {
    ...
    doLast {
        copy {
            from archivePath
            into 'path/to/other/destination'
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems like a more convenient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a [Copy task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) for the copying, and possibly add a ['finalizedBy' statement](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.html#org.gradle.api.DefaultTask:finalizedBy) on the Zip task.

Copying into multiple destinations is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467498/how-to-copy-to-multiple-destinations-with-gradle-copy-task).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's the approach I went for. Nevertheless I'd still be interested in how you could do something like that or if it's possible at the moment. It seems like you have to write an unnecessary (copy) task for what could be done by the task that's actually supposed to do that (zip).